# Pepper stem black and wrinkled leaves

Tags: leaves, peppers, stems, virus

my pepper is growing very slowly and I think it is sick.
[image]

Its stem seems dry with some black parts. Also the leaves are wrinkled. I have read that this could be a Pepper veinal marbre virus (PVMV). But I have not really found any information about a stem like this. Does anyone know what is happening with my plant? Is it a virus? Do I have to cut it out and keep the soil for another plant?

Comment: Black stems may be nothing. A caterpillar or other varmint is chewing on the leaves. I spray with soapy water.

Comment: Yes, I tracked the caterpillars and chased them. It was some time ago. Now what makes me afraid is the wrinkled leaves and the slow growing